How can I tell my Edge browser to forget about a domain?
I used to browse many locations on some webserver, https://the.dummy.server.com (not the real name). Now, for all sorts of reasons, that server is gone, and much of its content has gone elsewhere. Unfortunately, when I type in part of a URL on the new server (e.g. "bar"), I mostly get suggestions on https://the.dummy.server.com , e.g. https://the.dummy.server.com/foo/salad_bar while what I'm really after is, say, https://foocentral.com/salad_bar.
I would like to tell Microsoft's Edge browser to forget about URLs it knows and searches for completion/suggestion - but not all URLs, i.e. not clearing all private data - just this particular server, which no longer exists. Can I do that?

You should be able to remote the cache for specific websites within the Settings inside of Chrome. edge://settings/content/cookies?search=cookies

@Ramhound: I don't believe cookies is where I need to be looking...
